# Keep a part of edittext uneditable

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app I have a couple of checkboxes, that when checked combine the first part of an edittext. In the same edittext I would like to allow the user to append some text, while disallowing to delete the built text.

This is how it looks
[This part is build from checkbox combination, and can change in real time][This part is user defined]

Now is there a way to not allow the user to modify the first part of the edittext, but still allow the app to change this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly create a TextWatcher object and add it to your edittext.  In your textwatcher, you can store the constant text information in an instance variable.  Then, you can fill in the onTextChanged() and afterTextChanged() methods to create the type of behavior you are looking for.

For example, you can check the cursor position (using editText.getSelected()) to see if the user tried to change some of the text that shouldn't be changed-- if they do, then have some code to handle the case.

I know this isn't the best answer, but I don't yet have privilege to make a comment.  Hope this helps!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html here is the documentation for TextWatcher

Comment: Even though this is the right solution, because of the complexity of this whole thing, I decided to go with a textview and an edittext. Thanks nonetheless!